# Is it typical for a docker image to have over 900 vulnerabilities in an image scan?

Tags: docker, debian, gitlab-ci

I ran the ruby debian docker image through the gitlab container scan and it has come back with a list of over 900 CVEs with a large chunk dating from 2016 and 2017. This is a fresh version of the official ruby docker image. All of the CVEs are listed as coming from the debian 9 image. Is this a typical result from container scans, is there anything I can actually do about this? I would have thought the debian images would be kept up to date and secured.

The exact image pulled was `ruby:2.5.1` from dockerhub

Comment: Can you be more specific on which image and tag you pulled, and was it from the docker hub? Have you tried the Alpine based tags? And are patches available from Debian for the vulnerabilities you're seeing?

Comment: Do you have a hard dependency in 2.5.1, or would the latest patch under 2.5 be usable?

Comment: @BMitch No I could upgrade my ruby version. I did not expect the docker image to be unsupported so fast though.

Comment: It's typical for a very old image.  Don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience this is in fact typical, and I’ve seen two reasons it happens.

The first is that, particularly for language interpreters that can have C extensions, sometimes, the prepackaged image contains a full C build toolchain.  That includes Linux kernel headers.  Because you have Linux kernel headers, you’ll set off loud alarms from the security scanner that you have an out-of-date kernel, even though Docker itself doesn’t run the kernel.

The second is a little scarier.  If you look at https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby you’ll see there is an MRI 2.5.5 image now, and not a 2.5.1 image listed there.  General practice seems to be to build one image version for each minor release, but once a new patch release comes out, stop publishing updates for older patch releases.  That is, your 2.5.1 image probably does have some security issues, and there will never be a newer official image that fixes them.

The best solution to this I’ve found is to build my own language-interpreter base image, starting from the Linux distribution of your choice, and periodically rebuild it yourself.  Then it’s under your control and you’re sure to have security updates when you do releases.

Comment: I built a fresh copy of the ruby slim image and it dropped from 900 CVEs to 100. After looking up some of them about 90% seem completely unimportant and the rest are still open on debian itself so I think this looks like the best things can be

Answer (score 0):

> The exact image pulled was `ruby:2.5.1` from dockerhub

As David mentions, you'll stop seeing builds for one patch when the next patch comes out. Behind the scenes, if you configure docker hub to do your builds for you, what you'll see is docker depending on tags on your github repo, and when you tag your code, the build is triggered off of that. You can read more about their [automated builds here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/). So unless you repush an old tag, it won't get updated automatically. In this case, the 2.5.1 tag was last pushed 6 months ago, and there have been multiple 2.5.x releases that have superseded it.

You can clone the [ruby repo](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby) and perform your own builds based off of that on your own schedule. By pulling fresh base images, that would keep your image up to date.

You could also use an Alpine based ruby image which will have a much smaller base image. The reduced size means there are fewer pre-installed applications that could potentially be vulnerable. However, this comes with some usability challenges, like musl instead of libc, and some of those other pre-installed applications may have been useful.

The easiest answer is to not use a specific patch version when you have semver based version numbers. So instead of `ruby:2.5.1`, you can pull `ruby:2.5`, and when 2.5.2 came out, it would have updated the 2.5 tag for your next pull. There's even a simple `ruby:2` image that would automatically update you to the current 2.6 release, without pushing breaking changes from the 3.x release whenever that happens.

Lastly, if you like the Debian based install over the Alpine version, you can still switch to a minimized version of Debian with the slim images. In this case, there is a `ruby:2.5-slim` that would be smaller, while still keeping updates with the most recently 2.5 release.